# Advice: Template structure - php blocks in sidebar or someting else?

Tags: functions, sidebar

I'm trying to create certain modulair blocks which I can add to multiple pages in Wordpress. But I use sidebar-[name].php files for this, what is the best practice for this? Should you add them to a function or add them in a sidebar...

It feels Kinda off using many sidebar's. It would be nice if I could add them to a sub-folder in the template. Checkout the image. How do you do this?

[image]

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking here. Are you asking *how to include template parts in a WordPress Theme*, or *how to use PHP to modularize a template*?

Comment: Both actually. As you can see in the screenshot my base folder is getting crowded with files. So I want to modularize the theme using smaller files in folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say to add them as template parts as in content-[name].php. For instance in `page.php` you could have something like:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if (is_page( 'home' ) ){
                 get_template_part( 'content', 'benefits' );
                } elseif (is_page( 'Contact' ) ){
                 get_template_part( 'content', 'contact' ); 
                }  
             } 

            get_template_part( 'content', 'popup' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

It seems to make more sense as it is content after all.

Answer (score 2):

Who says you **can not** put template files into sub-directories?

Your custom-templates can be put wherever you want them to be - because it is you who includes them, anyway.

If you see the Codex on [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part#Using_with_theme_subfolders), you find the following:

```
get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'page' );
```

Comment: Nice addittion. So I added all the files to a "partials" folder, cleaned up the root very nice.